# What does this sentence mean？

Tags: php

```
public static function has_setting()
{
    return (self::count() > 0);
}
```

count() is a PHP funciton,prepend it with self,I wonder the meaning,thanks.
I know the self means this  class, I just wonder the meaning this **self::count()**

**Does this mean count the instance quantity of this class?**

I don't know why people son my question!you can give some advice other than stepping on it

I will improve my question, can you put away your feet?

Comment: `self` should reference to the current class, normally when you want to access to some ***static*** members of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like `count()` is a static function. when static functions are used it applies to all objects of the class not a particular object. So `self` means the current class. `self::count` means that the class is saying : apply this function on myself (all my objects).

Comment: would you tell me the meaning of _empty()

Comment: @shine It's a boolean function that tells you whether the variable is empty or not. You need to put that variable as parameter. You can find more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php . I'm not sure if there is a particular function in your class called _empty() but if there is, it seems like it is doing the same thing

Comment: So does it mean there must be a method called **count** defined in this class? and the method is not the one in PHP manual.right?

Comment: No. Both `count()` and `empty()` are in PHP manual so you don't have to define it in this class. Unless you want to implement a function for another purpose.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a static member there is no `$this` so you can only access static members of the class.

The `self` bit tells the compiler to used the static function of the same class.

Comment: would you tell me the meaning of _empty()

Comment: @shine  - Where is the class definition for `Validation`. Not physic